# My build.gradle is not recognised as manifest file for Github dependency graph/dependabot

Tags: java, github, gradle

I have a Github repo consisting of multiple programming languages (Java, Ruby, JS etc). After enabling the dependency graph I can see dependencies for some the the manifest files. However it does not seem to recognise my build.gradle file. Is there a way to configure which manifest files Github shall use?

My ultimate goal is to enable dependabot alerts for my whole project, but currently only my dependencies related to Ruby and JS are evaluated, not Java dependencies through Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Gradle does not seem to be supported.

https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1620